# Using RedisMetadataStore (RedisProperties) with a Redis cluster

Tags: spring-integration, spring-data-redis

We have a cluster of servers that are are monitoring a shared network mount for processing EDI files. We recently added code to use the RedisMetadataStore as follows:

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentMetadataStore metadataStore() {
    return new RedisMetadataStore(redisConnectionFactory);
 }

@Bean 
public FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter persistentAcceptOnceFileFilter() {
    return new FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(metadataStore(), "edi-file-locks");
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow flowInboundNetTransferFile(
        @Value("${edi.incoming.directory.netTransfers}") String inboundDirectory,
        @Value("${edi.incoming.age-before-ready-seconds:30}") int ageBeforeReadySeconds,
        @Value("${taskExecutor.inboundFile.corePoolSize:4}") int corePoolSize,
        @Qualifier("taskExecutorInboundFile") TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {

    //Setup a filter to only pick up a files older than a certain age, relative to the current time. This prevents cases
    //where something is writing to the file as the EDI processor is moving that file. 
    LastModifiedFileListFilter lastModifiedFilter = new LastModifiedFileListFilter();
    lastModifiedFilter.setAge(ageBeforeReadySeconds);
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(
                Files
                    .inboundAdapter(new File(inboundDirectory))
                    .locker(ediDocumentLocker())
                    .filter(new ChainFileListFilter<File>())
                    .filter(new IgnoreHiddenFileListFilter())
                    .filter(lastModifiedFilter)
                    .filter(persistentAcceptOnceFileFilter()),
                e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(20000).maxMessagesPerPoll(corePoolSize).taskExecutor(taskExecutor)))
            .channel(channelInboundFile())
            .get();     
}
```

This was working fine in our lower environments, however, we use a Redis cluster in our production environment and when we deployed to that environment we are encountering an exception :

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: WATCH is currently not supported in cluster mode.
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisClusterConnection.watch(JedisClusterConnection.java:2450)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultStringRedisConnection.watch(DefaultStringRedisConnection.java:951)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate$24.doInRedis(RedisTemplate.java:885)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:204)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:166)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.watch(RedisTemplate.java:882)
at org.springframework.data.redis.support.collections.DefaultRedisMap$2.execute(DefaultRedisMap.java:225)
at org.springframework.data.redis.support.collections.DefaultRedisMap$2.execute(DefaultRedisMap.java:221)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:226)
at org.springframework.data.redis.support.collections.DefaultRedisMap.replace(DefaultRedisMap.java:221)
at org.springframework.data.redis.support.collections.RedisProperties.replace(RedisProperties.java:238)
at org.springframework.integration.redis.metadata.RedisMetadataStore.replace(RedisMetadataStore.java:154)
at org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AbstractPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.accept(AbstractPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.java:83)
at org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AbstractFileListFilter.filterFiles(AbstractFileListFilter.java:40)
at org.springframework.integration.file.filters.ChainFileListFilter.filterFiles(ChainFileListFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.integration.file.DefaultDirectoryScanner.listFiles(DefaultDirectoryScanner.java:95)
at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.scanInputDirectory(FileReadingMessageSource.java:387)
at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.receive(FileReadingMessageSource.java:366)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:224)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:245)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: WATCH is currently not supported in cluster mode.
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisClusterConnection.watch(JedisClusterConnection.java:2450)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultStringRedisConnection.watch(DefaultStringRedisConnection.java:951)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate$24.doInRedis(RedisTemplate.java:885)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:204)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:166)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.watch(RedisTemplate.java:882)
at org.springframework.data.redis.support.collections.DefaultRedisMap$2.execute(DefaultRedisMap.java:225)
at org.springframework.data.redis.support.collections.DefaultRedisMap$2.execute(DefaultRedisMap.java:221)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:226)
at org.springframework.data.redis.support.collections.DefaultRedisMap.replace(DefaultRedisMap.java:221)
at org.springframework.data.redis.support.collections.RedisProperties.replace(RedisProperties.java:238)
at org.springframework.integration.redis.metadata.RedisMetadataStore.replace(RedisMetadataStore.java:154)
at org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AbstractPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.accept(AbstractPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter.java:83)
at org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AbstractFileListFilter.filterFiles(AbstractFileListFilter.java:40)
at org.springframework.integration.file.filters.ChainFileListFilter.filterFiles(ChainFileListFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.integration.file.DefaultDirectoryScanner.listFiles(DefaultDirectoryScanner.java:95)
at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.scanInputDirectory(FileReadingMessageSource.java:387)
at org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource.receive(FileReadingMessageSource.java:366)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:224)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:245)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.access$000(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:58)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:190)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$1.call(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:186)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint$Poller$1.run(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:353)
at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor$1.run(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
```

Looking a little closer, it looks like this store is using RedisProperties as a backing store, which in turn is using features of the Redis client that are not supported with the Cluster client. Has anyone worked around this issue? Perhaps written an alternate store that does support a Redis cluster?

Comment: Related GH issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/2207. There is also JIRA for other key-value solution: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4065

Comment: There is no answers on the matter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44942854/spring-boot-data-redis-cluster-not-support-watch-method

Comment: I'm afraid we can't do that with the current impl for Redis cluster.